# improve search for a div attributte every hover event with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have several divs like:

```
<section class="card-container">
    <div class="card over" data-direction="right" gal="gal1">
        <div class="front">
                <h2>yellow flowers</h2>
                <h4>(Right)</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="back">
            <img src="http://images.fanpop.com/images/image_uploads/Flower-Wallpaper-flowers-249398_1693_1413.jpg"
            width="100%;" height="100%;" alt="" />
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Also Ihave a jquery that depending on div, it searches a efect "right,left,bottom,top" to apply to div, then searches the type of gal, and changes the image it has as a value for other image stored in corresponding array

So, I think to improve the code, I would make a dictionary with the values for each div, instead of applying

```
img = $(this).find('img');
```

every time the user is hovering...

Is there a way to improve the code, also i was wondering is it good to wait till all images are loaded or something? [here is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fUsPh/37/)

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand your problem. Are you asking if it's a good idea to cache jQuery selectors? In that case the answer is yes. Do you need to wait for images to load? No, it is enough to wait for the DOM to load. Are you looking for code-review or to discuss how to write performant javascript? check the javascript chat room here in SO or codereview.stackexchange

Comment: Yeah, I think is enough to search only once for `img = $(this).find('img');` so, I do not have to do over, for each div, but what would be the best approach

Comment: Best in what regard? If you're asking if it's better to cache your jQuery selectors the answer is defiantly **yes**.

Comment: speed, and avoiding silly searches

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load the images on loading by put the images in a div and set the prop of the div in css to: position: absolute; left: -5000px;

HTML:

```
<div id="allimages"><img 1><img 2> etc.. </div>
```

Css:

```
#allimages {
  postion: absolute;
  left: -5000px;
}
```

And there alot other way to:
you can catch all img with Jquery and put them in the div when dom is ready

Comment: ok, but how to improve the search of gal image attribute, using `img = $(this).find('img');`  ?, is it possible to do it only once for each object?

Comment: That's a pretty silly way to load all the images in advance. you can do this in JS with `new Image().src = "your image url here"`

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Yes but i quote: ("And there alot other way to:")

at cMinor yes, wait letme try

Comment: i need to go, i will try something when i'm back on ;)